# ODR of template class with static constexpr member

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, constexpr, one-definition-rule

I know, there are many answered question about linkage of a static (constexpr) members.

But I wonder, why using a template class out-of-line definition works in a header file but not for a specialized class.

a) This works without linker error:

```
template<typename, typename>
struct Foobar;

template<typename T>
struct Foobar<int, T> {
  static constexpr std::array<int, 1> a = {{1}};
};

template<typename T>
constexpr std::array<int, 1> Foobar<int, T>::a;

// foo.cpp
std::cout << Foobar<int, int>::a[0] << "\n";

// bar.cpp
std::cout << Foobar<int, int>::a[0] << "\n";
```

The objdump of:

foo.o: `0000000000000000  w    O .rodata._Z6FoobarIiiE1aE    0000000000000004 _Z6FoobarIiiE1aE`

bar.o: `0000000000000000  w    O .rodata._Z6FoobarIiiE1aE    0000000000000004 _Z6FoobarIiiE1aE`

Linked file: `0000000000475a30  w    O .rodata  0000000000000004 _Z6FoobarIiiE1aE`

b) This does not (multiple definition):

```
template<typename>
struct Foobar;

template<>
struct Foobar<int> {
  static constexpr std::array<int, 1> a = {{1}};
};
constexpr std::array<int, 1> Foobar<int>::a;

// foo.cpp
std::cout << Foobar<int>::a[0] << "\n";

// bar.cpp
std::cout << Foobar<int>::a[0] << "\n";
```

The objdump of:

foo.o `0000000000000100 g     O .rodata        0000000000000004 _Z6FoobarIiE1aE`

bar.o: `0000000000000420 g     O .rodata        0000000000000004 _Z6FoobarIiE1aE`

What we see, the out-of-line definition has different addresses inside the object files (example b)).

My question to you:

1. Is it save to use the template trick? What are the disadvantage?
2. Would it be useful to relax the definition of odr for such cases like b in the future?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "*Would it be useful to relax the definition of odr for such cases like b in the future?*" Already in C++17: constexpr static data members are implicitly `inline`.

Comment: Lovely! Can't wait for it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [basic.def.odr]/6:

> There can be more than one definition of a class type (Clause 9), enumeration type (7.2), inline function with
>   external linkage (7.1.2), class template (Clause 14), non-static function template (14.5.6), static data member
>   of a class template (14.5.1.3), member function of a class template (14.5.1.1), or template specialization for
>   which some template parameters are not specified (14.7, 14.5.5) in a program provided that each definition
>   appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements. ...

The effect of this rule is that every *template-declaration* behaves as though it is inline. (But it does not extend to *explicit-instantiation* and *explicit-specialization* declarations.)

In the first snippet, you have

```
template<typename T>
constexpr std::array<int, 1> Foobar<int, T>::a;
```

which is a *template-declaration* and therefore is allowed to be multiply defined. In the second snippet, you have

```
constexpr std::array<int, 1> Foobar<int>::a;
```

which is not a *template-declaration*: the definition itself is not templated, even though the thing being defined happens to be a specialization of a template.

> My question to you:
>
> 1. Is it save to use the template trick? What are the disadvantage?

There is no "trick" here. If you want to define the member for *all* `Foo<T>`, then you have no choice but to put the definition in the header file. If you want to define the member for *one specific* `Foo<T>` such as `Foo<int>`, then you must not put the definition in the header file (until C++17, which introduces inline variables.) There is no trick because what you are supposed to do depends on your specific goal.

(Your second question was answered in the comment section.)